# how to set line width in gvim to be 80 characters even if maximize the gvim window?

Tags: vim

I am in win7+gvim7.4 ,how to set line width in gvim?
In my _vimrc file:

```
set nowrap
set tw=80
set formatoptions=tnmM
```

when i open a file with gvim ,
1. the window is small window ,and 80 character in one line.
2. when Maximize windows to fill the entire gvim screen,i found that 157
characters can be displayed in one line.

how can i set 80 character in one line envn if you  Maximize gvim window ?
where can i change the 157 characters in one maximized gvim window?

[image]
 [image]

Comment: It appears from your screenshots that somehow `'wrap'` is still set. Do this to figure out where it got set, apparently something is overriding your _vimrc setting: `:verbose set wrap?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you worry that the window width is too large in maximized GVIM, you can create a vertical dummy window next to it, e.g. with `:bot vnew | wincmd p`.

My [LimitWindowSize plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3238) offers a command to reduce the current window size by placing an empty padding window next to it.

Other plugins like [DistractFree - An WriteRoom/DarkRoom/OmniWrite like plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4357) go further and add padding on all sides around a single centered window (and turn off embellishments), so that you can focus on the current editing task.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding the implication of setting `tw`. Here's what `:help tw` shows:

```
'textwidth' 'tw'    number  (default 0)
            local to buffer
            {not in Vi}
    Maximum width of text that is being inserted.  A longer line will be
    broken after white space to get this width.  A zero value disables
    this.  'textwidth' is set to 0 when the 'paste' option is set.  When
    'textwidth' is zero, 'wrapmargin' may be used.  See also
    'formatoptions' and |ins-textwidth|.
    When 'formatexpr' is set it will be used to break the line.
    NOTE: This option is set to 0 when 'compatible' is set.
```

The value of `tw` simply indicates the column number at which a break occurs when you are in insert mode. It does not change how a line is displayed when it is longer than the value of `tw`.

Lines can become longer than `tw` by various means: pasting from the clipboard, pasting from a register, joining two lines, etc. None of those operations are limited by the value of `tw`.